# Control another application using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to control other application by simulating mouse movement and keyboard input. How do I accomplish this in C#? Is it even possible?

Comment: Maybe Jon Skeet is the only one who can do that :)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412598/how-to-interact-with-an-application-programmatically. I found that by searching http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Control+another+application

Comment: However accepted answer for this question is different than the accepted answer for the duplicate (both provide a reasonable solution).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Have you looked at <strike>[White](http://www.codeplex.com/white)</strike>  [TestStack](https://github.com/TestStack/White)?

Sample code:

```
Application application = Application.Launch("foo.exe");
Window window = application.GetWindow("bar", InitializeOption.NoCache);

Button button = window.Get<Button>("save");
button.Click();
```

I don't think it can get better than that. The library is created by ThoughtWorks.

Comment: I was trying to browse White project's documentation and it started giving errors! BTW, 'White' will give you OO approach to control Windows based applications.

Comment: I'm trying to access Spotify (A music program) and click the play button, but it seems to be completely graphical because I can't find any handles or anything with spy++. How would I do this?

Comment: @PontusMagnusson did you managed it somehow? I am having the same issue as you.

Comment: @Twenty I did, but unfortunately I dont have the code anymore. I believe I queued windows events to control the different elements of the application. Today I think I'd use the Spotify API tho.

Answer (score 4):

See "To send a keystroke to a different application" on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use p/invoke, I stole the following code for mouse clicks in random spots on a button with a known handle:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum MouseEventFlags
    {
        LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
        LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
        MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
        MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
        MOVE = 0x00000001,
        ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
        RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
        RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rectangle
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int Width;
        public int Height;
    }

    private static void Click(IntPtr Handle)
    {
        lock (typeof(MouseAction))
        {
            Rectangle buttonDesign;

            GetWindowRect(Handle, out buttonDesign);
            Random r = new Random();

            int curX = 10 + buttonDesign.X + r.Next(100 - 20);
            int curY = 10 + buttonDesign.Y + r.Next(60 - 20);

            SetCursorPos(curX, curY);
            //Mouse Right Down and Mouse Right Up
            mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN, curX, curY, 0, 0);
            mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP, curX, curY, 0, 0);  
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(
        long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rectangle rect);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/), it's freeware, and it has a dll version that you can import into C# (DllImport). It allows you to click on controls, write strings to edit boxes, make combobox selections etc on another application from C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) Native Win32 API. [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) this method from the User32.dll. You can use this API to send both keyboard & mouse messages

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same: to use the mouse i used this class

(you need to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`)

```
public class MouseClick1    //public is important here**
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);


        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;


        public int CoordX { get; set; }    
        public int CoordY { get; set; }

                public void Click1()
        {

            Cursor.Position = new Point(CoordX, CoordY);

            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        }

    }
```

and after on your form1 (presuming the name is form1) you can

```
 public partial class form1 : Form
    {

 MouseClick1 button1 = new MouseClick1();
 MouseClick1 button2 = new MouseClick1();
```

[...]

```
    public void Simulate_button1and2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       button1.CoordX = 1652;   //random coordinates
       button1.CoordY = 225;
       button2.CoordX = 1650;
       button2.CoordY = 250;

       button1.Click1();
       button1.Click2();
```

}
}

To have the coordinates on your pointer, I use a timer and a label:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Coord.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString() + " : " + Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();  //Premet d'avoir les coord en direct

        }
```

Work fine with me.

Comment: In your code `button1.Click2();` should be `button2.Click1();`.