# C# - Control another application's windows using Thoughtworks White

Tags: c#, controls, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm creating a C# program and I need to control another application. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134993)
 example, but it doesn't really work for me (or at least I can't make it work).
1) The application is already running (so I can't use `Application application = Application.Launch("foo.exe");`
2) It has a textbox and I need to read what's written in it.
3) Then I want to press one of its buttons (This can be done with that: `Button button = window.Get<Button>("save"); button.Click();`

I also searched Google, but I didn't find anything working.
Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation doesn't mention it, but [`Application.Attach()`](http://white.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/43110#433038) allows you to access a program that is already running. From there, I would expect everything would work as documented.