# Access the state of control in Winforms from another application

Tags: winforms

I have a sample winform application called (Myapp.exe) with a form and a button. I will launch this application (.exe) from another application.

My questions here is. After launching the (Myapp.exe) application from another application (console or winform), i need to access the state of the button in (Myapp.exe) application. How this is achieved?? Is it possible? Can any one please me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you need to realise that from an outside point of view a button is a window (with a handle) whose parent is the form (also a window with a handle), and its state may not be accessible with quite the same useful names as the properties in WinForms show it.

For example, this C++ code will work on a C# app even if that app is being run through the debugger:

```
HWND hwndCSharp = ::FindWindow(NULL,_T("Form1") ); 
if (hwndCSharp != NULL) 
{
    // Walk the window's child windows (controls / views): 
    HWND hwndChild = ::GetWindow(hwndCSharp, GW_CHILD); 
    while (hwndChild != NULL) 
    {
        // Get state here... 

        hwndChild = ::GetWindow(hwndChild, GW_HWNDNEXT); 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this has already been discussed in stack.so here is just a same code just give it try.

```
  Application application = Application.Launch("Myapp.exe");
       Window window = application.GetWindow("bar", InitializeOption.NoCache);

       Button button = window.Get<Button>("button1");
       button.Click();
```

Comment: Can you share me some pointers where this has been discussed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134993/control-another-application-using-c-sharp

Comment: What is `Application.GetWindow` or `Application.Launch`? This might be C# code, but it's not using methods provided by the BCL...

Comment: Here is what i'm looking for http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/02/project-white-automated-ui-testing.html