# Read properties of another running .NET program

Tags: .net

Can program a.exe read some values/properties (e.g. button's text) of currently running program b.exe? If it is possible, how can it be done?

Both programs are written using .NET framework.

More details:
I'm writing unit tests for another program. I need to somehow obtain legend text from one DataVisualization.Charting.Chart control.

Comment: You will have to implement an interface through which requests are handled. Something like WCF or so allows you inter-application communication.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What information do you need from the other program? Is it _your_ program? Can the two programs cooperate?

Comment: If a button's text is what you are after then a UI Automation library is the way to go.  Like Project White.  The question is too vague.

Comment: Actually I need to obtain some text from Chart control. Any idea how I can do that? I can't modify the program that contains the Chart control.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with inter-process communication (IPC).

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8119f66k(v=vs.100).aspx

Hope it helped!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the program that contains the Chart control, so this solution won't work.

Comment: Maybe this will help then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134993/control-another-application-using-c-sharp