# What is the assembly reference for accessing another application?

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, .net-assembly, using

I am trying to access another program that is running, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134993/control-another-application-using-c-sharp) code:

```
Application application = Application.Launch("foo.exe");
Window window = application.GetWindow("bar", InitializeOption.NoCache);

Button button = window.Get<Button>("save");
button.Click();
```

But when I try to run it, it says:

> The type or namespace name "Window" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am wondering if anyone knows the using reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses the TestStack.White framework. The easiest way to get is is to reference the nuget package.

https://github.com/TestStack/White

http://www.nuget.org/packages/TestStack.White/

Comment: And where do I get that?

Comment: Have you ever heard of nuget? Nuget is a vs addin that allows you to reference complete frameworks. It automatically downloads required files and adds references. Nuget is available for vs starting from vs 2010.

Comment: Never heard of it. How do I get it?

Comment: Go to addin manager in vs. Install nuget. Then, in your solution, right click the references node and pick nuget as the reference source. This will bring the package browser which shows all available packages.