# vbs script which immitates mouse clicks

Tags: vbscript

I have a program which can't be killed with taskkill or pskill. Now my idea was to let a vba script fake mouse clicks and run this script from a batch file.

My question, can anyone tell me of give me an example how to do this? I don't know how you call this method.

Edit: It seem it can be done with special sendkeys commands.

Comment: VBA is not VBScript, similar, but not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do, I would recommend [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/). It's a simple VB-like scripting language that you can use to simulate mouse clicks, key presses, etc.

See this question: [How to interact with an application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412598/how-to-interact-with-an-application-programmatically/413087#413087)